# How to get average by month in Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have been trying to get average values per month for the rainfall. There are dates, hours and values (hours don't matter here since average will be of all values per month).

```
class TimeSeries(models.Model):
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    hour = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.FloatField()
```

What i have tried is:

```
delta = relativedelta(months=1)

dateStart=TimeSeries.objects.values('date').order_by('date').values_list('date',flat=True).first()

dateEnd=TimeSeries.objects.values('date').order_by('date').values_list('date',flat=True).last()

for i in range(len(stationNumbers)):
     while dateStart <= dateEnd:

         timeSeries = TimeSeries.objects.filter(
            station__number=stationNumbers[i],date__range=[dateStart,dateStart+delta]
         ).annotate(
               month=TruncMonth('date')
         ).values(
               'station__number','month'
         ).annotate(
               value=Avg('value')
         ).order_by(
               'station__number','month'
         )
```

I have tried making some changes into the query but it doesn't work in any way. Should i be using raw SQL here? and Can someone kindly help? i am new to Django. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
There are 24 records per date because there are 24 hours in a day that is why the records are per hour wise. Can it be a problem in getting average per month if there are repetitive dates?

**Edit 2:**
Here is the Dataset(note that the data is for 3 years):

| Name | Date | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Station B | 01/01/2015 | 0:00 | 55 |
| Station B | 01/01/2015 | 1:00 | 51 |
| Station B | 01/01/2015 | 2:00 | 54 |
| Station B | 01/01/2015 | 3:00 | 58 |

Comment: What exact error are you getting? Please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback. Or the exact output if there is no error

Comment: there are no errors just a bunch of values that are either empty, or values like 1.7777777 all over the results for different queries, which is incorrect.

Comment: to get avg value per each month you do simply this `TimeSeries.objects.filter().values("date__month").annotate(average=Avg("value"))` this will get you all the months/records. if you want for specific range do provide a range in filter.

Comment: @HemalPatel I have done the same, after applying filter it doesn't give correct output. the output is a lot of values so cannot  put here. but the output is the same for all stations. and it includes null values everywhere except the center of the array. the central array outputs an array of 17 values.

Answer (score 3):

You can just truncate per month, so:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

timeSeries = TimeSeries.objects.values(
    'station__number', month=TruncMonth('date')
).annotate(
    avg=Avg('value')
).order_by(
    'station__number', 'month'
)
```

This will return a queryset of dictionaries with the `station__number`, the `month` and the average value `avg`.

We thus can simply fetch all data in bulk. There is no need to loop, filter, etc. So a sample record can look like:

```
{'station__number': 14, 'month': date(1958, 3, 1), 'avg': 14.25 }
```

based on the answer however, you want to group by year:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear

timeSeries = TimeSeries.objects.values(
    'station__number', year=ExtractYear('date')
).annotate(
    avg=Avg('value')
).order_by(
    'station__number', 'year'
)
```

You can post-process the data with:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

data = {
    station: {
        ri.year: ri.avg for ri in rs
    }
    for station, rs in groupby(timeseries, attrgetter('station__number'))
}

years = [d for datum in data.values() for d in datum]
mn, mx = min(dt_range), max(dt_range)
for vals in data.values():
    for vl in range(mn, mx+1):
        vals.setdefault(vl, None)
```

Then `data` is a dictionary that maps each station number to a dictionary that maps years to the average.

Comment: The number of values in the array returned are 100 which is correct because there are 100 months. but the values are incorrect, all are null except central 56th value which has another array(5) inside it.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAnwar: an array? Value should be a scalar float, not an array of floats. Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Dataset is bulk with 16 arrays, each having 3 arrays, each of which has station number, as well as array(100) of dates and array(100) of values.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAnwar: so `value` is not a `FloatField`, but an `ArrayField`? Please *don't* do that! Your database is not in 1NF then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF which means (as you figured out here), it is harder to maintain, query, etc.

Comment: it is a float field as i have described the in the model above

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAnwar: but then were do the arrays originate from? It would be helpful if you give some sampledata to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure, it has been provided in the question above.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAnwar: but you omitted the `for` loop and the filtering, right? For the other ones, there is probably no data. What database do you use?

Comment: for loop and filtering is provided in the code above and it is used in the code too. Database is Postgresql

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAnwar: but it makes no sense to do that: the query in the answer will return records for *each* combination of station and month for which there is data, so all in a single query. If it is not in the queryset, there is simply no data for the combination of the station and the month in question. This is thus the *only* query you need to perform *once*.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. A point to note is that the data was too much for a chart if filtered by month. so i filtered by year.

So i just got all the data per year (which is per hour data), converted it into a list then got the average manually.

Previously i tried to break down the query into sub queries by first getting station, then getting data per year then using `aggregate()` to get average but it did not work since Django has limitations on applying subqueries on queries.

here is the code:

```
data=[]
delta = relativedelta(years=1)     #add one year to the date in the below while loop


for i in range(0,len(stationNumbers)):
    timeSeriesGraphDates=[]
    timeSeriesGraphValues=[]
    dateStart=TimeSeries.objects.values('date').order_by('date').values_list('date',flat=True).first()
    dateEnd=TimeSeries.objects.values('date').order_by('date').values_list('date',flat=True).last()


    while dateStart <= dateEnd:

        timeSeries=list(TimeSeries.objects.filter(station__number=stationNumbers[i],date__year=dateStart.year).values_list('value',flat=True))

        average_value=sum(timeSeries) / len(timeSeries) if timeSeries else None

        timeSeriesGraphValues.append(average_value)
        timeSeriesGraphDates.append(dateStart)

        dateStart += delta
    data.append([stationNames[i],timeSeriesGraphValues,timeSeriesGraphDates])
```

Comment: please *don't*: this will blow up the number of queries, making it slow and makes it even possible that other queries lock. It can render the server non-responsive and If you deploy this on a third-party hosting service can even cost *a lot*.

Comment: Thankyou  @WillemVanOnsem for informing, please suggest a solution as the solutions aren't working

Comment: what is not working with the updated answer (aggregates per year, and `None` if no data available).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i will try your new method if possible and will respond. thanks alot for  the method :)